# How to pytest a python function with raise exception

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, pytest

My folder struct looks like this:

```
|- src
    |- __init__.py
    |- funcA.py
    |- util.py
|- tests
   |- __init__.py
   |- test_funcA.py
   |- test_util.py
```

My goal is to test a function in funcA.py

```
def f():
   try:
     helper()
   except Exception as e:
     raise Exception('error: fail to call helper')
```

The helper function in util.py

```
def helper():
   try:
     #do something
   except Exception as e:
     raise Exception('error: fail to do something')
```

The unit test I write for f() is not cover these two lines `except Exception as e:
     raise Exception('error: fail to call helper')`

Here is my testcase for f

```
def test__f():
    with mock.patch('src.utils.helper', side_effect=Exception('fail to call helper')):
        from src import funcA
        with pytest.raises(Exception):
            funcA.f()
```

How to write unit test to cover f's raise exception? Thanks

Comment: I didn't quite get it. What do you mean by "`f`'s raise exception"?

Comment: it should work, there is nothing wrong unless you have duplicated func name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the "src.utils.helper" is wrong. I guess you should use "src.funcA.helper".